# What is the difference between a power law exponent and the Pareto exponent?

Tags: macroeconomics, pareto-efficiency, academic-graduate, wealth, r

I use the [poweRlaw](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/poweRlaw.pdf) package in R to fit a power law to my data. I am trying to figure out what is the value of the Pareto exponent.

Assume the probability mass function is defined by:

$$
p(x) = \frac{\alpha-1}{x_{min}} \left(\frac{x}{x_{min}} \right)^{-\alpha}
$$

and the complementary cumulative density function is defined by:

$$
P(x) = \int_x ^\infty p(x’) dx’ = \left(\frac{x}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\alpha + 1}
$$

Is the Pareto exponent $\alpha$ or $- \alpha + 1$ or  $\alpha - 1$?
In most literature, the CCDF is used to describe the income/wealth distribution, and $-(\alpha-1)$ is the slope of the CCDF on a log-log plot, so $\alpha-1$ seems the most intuitive. I'm pretty sure the R library [poweRlaw](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/poweRlaw.pdf) returns $\alpha$ as defined above.
I am using [Newman](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0412004) as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A random variable $X$ has a Pareto distribution with Pareto exponent
>   $\theta$ if  $$\text{P}(X>x)=\begin{cases} 
>  \left(\frac{x}{x_m}\right)^\theta \quad \text{ if } x\geq x_{min}\\  \
>  \ 1 \quad \quad \quad  \text{ if } x<x_{min} \end{cases}$$

In this case, the Pareto exponent is $\theta = \alpha - 1$. Remember that $P(X>x)=\int_x^\infty p(x')\mathrm{d}x'$.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.